# Custom Attribute will Not Display in Product List View Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, php

I am attempting to display certain custom attributes on our product list page. To do this I have followed the instructions on the Magento Commerce forum and have tested this method to work. I can't post a link since I am only allowed to post two links as a new user.

We are using a custom template. So I added the folder structure “/app/design/frontend/yardandpool/yap/template/catalog/product” and then uploaded the new “list.phtml” file to the product folder. Then, under “Custom Design” in the admin section for the category I have the custom template folder selected.

The attribute I am trying to display is a “Key #” for the particular product. It should display above the product name. As you can see here, it does not…

http://50.23.233.222/~yardandp/index.php/swimming-pool-supplies-accessories/swimming-pool-parts/test-parts1.html

But, then I created a custom template folder to the “base” folder. I created “/app/design/frontend/base/yardandpool/template/catalog/product” and put the same “list.phtml” file in the product folder. I then created a second test category and selected this folder for the “Custom Design” in the admin section. Obviously, the layout is not correct, but if you scroll down to where the product is located you will see the custom attribute “Key #” is displayed.

http://50.23.233.222/~yardandp/index.php/swimming-pool-supplies-accessories/swimming-pool-parts/test-parts2.html

What would be the reason it would be displayed here but not on both category pages? I can’t seem to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Enable template hints and check that the custom list.phtml is actually being lodaded.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes have an option "Used in Product Listing (Depends on design theme)" that needs to be checked to be, err, used in product lists.

The reason for this feature is products have many attributes that aren't needed on category pages and so are left unloaded to save time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But we do have this selected in the attribute settings. As stated above, it is being displayed when the "list.phtml" file is inserted into on template, just not another.

Comment: Are other changes to the same file also being ignored? For example if you put a big "HELLO WORLD!" text in a visible place..?